# Get specific values from object when mapping through nested object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I want to return an array with specific values of _time & _value. The function that I made is as followed:

```
getMachineData(data) {
    console.log(data)
    const result = data.map((innerArray) => {
        console.log(typeof innerArray)
        console.log(innerArray)
        // Map over the inner array
        return innerArray.map((item) => {
            console.log(item)
            return ({
                time: item._time,
                value: item._value
            });
        });
    });
    console.log(result);
};
```

But in this code the last console.log is never hit.

The innerArray data is as followed:

```
{ "result": "_result", "table": 0, "_start": "2021-01-06T14:35:53Z", "_stop": "2022-01-06T14:35:53Z", "_time": "2021-10-11T10:58:30Z", "_value": 0, "_field": "approved", "_measurement": "oee-data", "end_time_str": "2021-10-11T10:59:00Z", "machine": "almo", "start_time_str": "2021-10-11T10:58:30Z" }
```

The output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

innerArray is an `Object`, so dont have to iterate. Just access the value directly. Replace below code

```
return innerArray.map((item) => {
            console.log(item)
            return ({
                time: item._time,
                value: item._value
            });
        });
```

with

```
return {
         time: innerArray._time,
         value: innerArray._value
       };
```

The optimized code will look like

```
getMachineData(data) {
    const result = data.map(({_time, _value}) => ({time: _time, value:_value }));
    console.log(result);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your innerArray is not not an Array but an Object. You can not map over an Object like innerArray.map... which will probably throw an error.